# PHP: Is php_sapi_name() safe (can the user manipulate it)?

Tags: php, security

can the user manipulate the value which is returned by php_sapi_name()?

I have a script which looks like this:

```
if( php_sapi_name() !== "cli" ){
   die( "NoAccess" );
}

// Do some admin stuff
```

This script should only (!) be called through command line. Is the code above safe? Or can somebody call the script through HTTP and execute it beyond the if condition?

Comment: If nobody is supposed to access this script directly via HTTP, then you should place it outside of the http root folder.

Comment: I know it is best practice to do so, but in this case it is not possible. I will deny the access through .htaccess, but I want to be 100% safe even if the .htaccess fails so thats why I want to put the code there.

Answer (score 4):

`php_sapi_name()`'s return value is safe to rely on.  It's not generated from user data.

You shouldn't have this script accessible to your web server though if you don't want it to be called from your web server.  If you cared about safety, this script wouldn't be accessible at all.

You also mentioned `.htaccess`... don't use that, use a proper config file elsewhere.  `.htaccess` has to be loaded and parsed for every request, which is not efficient.

Comment: And the source for the function: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fa45f64bd87b62f655e6d99c1a088efa5772b5fe/ext/standard/info.c#L1326